# Exclude IP Address from FreeRadius?

Tags: linux, freeradius

I tried searching elsewhere, but couldnt find anything relevant. So I thought I might give it a shot here.
Is there anyway I can exclude a certain IP Address from accounting?
I have a file server running which shouldn't affect users usage stats.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but here we go:

You can use unlang to filter for IP-Addresses, either with hardcoded values or for example via SQL:

```
if ("%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}" != "10.16.1.1") {
    # do your usual stuff here
}
```

SQL:

```
if ("%{sql:SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounting_excluded_nas WHERE ip == '%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}'}" == 0)
```

For full documentation on the language, try the "unlang" manpage.
From this point on, there are many ways to exclude the accounting packet, either "reject"-ing (which would not send a Accounting-Response packet back), to wrapping the rest of the usual configuration into an if-block (as shown above).

You could also use the RADIUS attribute NAS-IP-Address, but a NAS is not required to send these with its packets.

(For IPv6, replace the text inside the %{} with Packet-Src-IPv6-Address)